# I had build the image and run the container in port 3000and its running now but when i try to access the application in browser it refuse to connect

Tags: dockerfile

**index.py**

```
    from flask import Flask
    #from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    @app.route('/api', methods=['GET'])
    def index():
        return "Hello, World!"
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

**requirements.txt file**

```
    flask
```

**Dockerfile**

```
    FROM python:3.12.0a5-alpine3.17
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY . /app
    RUN pip install --retries 5 -r requirements.txt
    EXPOSE 3000
    CMD ["python" ,"index.py"]
```

**when i run  `sudo docker port  90da591d332c`**

```
    3000/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:3000
    3000/tcp -> :::3000
```

**when i run  `sudo iptables -L`**

```
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    
    Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
    DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
    
    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    
    Chain DOCKER (1 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:3000
    
    Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
    
    Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
    
    Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

When I access the app in browser:

[image: When I access the app in browser]

I run `sudo iptables -L` and `sudo lsof -i :<port-number>` to check the firewall and ports

Comment: Isn't Flask's default port `5000`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok I changed the port to 5000 but its the same problem